# Wake on LAN in Asus M5A97 doesn't work

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have M5A97 R2.0 and have enabled "Power on by PME device" in BIOS as in this thread [WOL for Asus M5A97 built in Realtek Network Adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/339416/wol-for-asus-m5a97-built-in-realtek-network-adapter/885552#885552)

I run Debian Jessie on the WOL server and followed this guide https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan
ethtool gave by default this:

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
```

So I didn't have to change anything there. Have also checked the equivalent configs in Windows 10 but they were also already enabled by default.

The magic packet is sent from an Ubuntu laptop with ethernet in the same network. I have tried both tools *wakeonlan*(port 7 and 9) and *etherwake*. The MAC-address I'm sending to I got from ifconfig on the Debian machine and have checked it several times.

When sniffing the traffic with wireshark on the Debian I can see the WOL packet being broadcasted from *wakeonlan* tool. The *etherwake* tool sends direct to the MAC and it also arrives. They just don't wake up the computer when it is shut down. I have also tried to hibernate and suspend it instead of shut down but still nothing.

Update 1: Apparently WOL works for sleep mode and hibernate but not for shut down in windows 10 so it might be a Linux problem. I accept that it won't work for shut down but it should at least work for suspend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a driver problem and this is what I did. I write down all I did even if it wasn't a part of the solution.

First I updated the BIOS and enabled Power on by PME device again afterwards. Still not working. 
Then I installed a package called firmware-realtek but still not working. 
If I added the letter b as i broadcast in "Wake-on: bg" it suddenly work because it enables wake on for all broadcasting on the network. Magic packets still didn't work though so it was probably something with the network device after all. So I installed another driver from realteks website instead and now it's working like a charm. It's even working when the computer is completely shut down.

Afterwards I uninstalled the firmware-realtek package and it still works but I don't know if the BIOS update had to do anything with the success. After the second driver install, Wake-on: g was no longer default so I had to make those changes as the debian wiki described.

Realtek drivers can be found here www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Answer (score 0):

How about enabling "Wake on LAN" in your bios settings? Also, not every PC supports wake on LAN support. Make sure to check if your pc/laptop is capable of this feature and enable it in your BIOS settings.